# Как с помощью htaccess создать public папку для статических файлов?

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Есть например директория /App/Public/Theme/style.css
В html файле подключается стиль

```
<link href="/App/Public/Themes/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Вопрос, в том, что можно ли как нибудь заставить apache отдавать статические файлы из определённой директории, при запросе

```
/Theme/.*?(css|gif....)
 <link href="/Themes/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

?

Comment: Подниму тему.

Answer (score 1):

[Ссылка на доки Апача](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) 
С поддержкой регулярок

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/www/(.+/)?[0-9]{3}">
    # ...
</DirectoryMatch>
```

would match directories in /www/ that consisted of three numbers

Comment: Править конфиги апача не желательно. Нужно, как-то через htaccess